# Problem in Proteus With 555 monostable trigger

Tags: 555, monostable

I try to make a MonoStable in proteus.
Below is my circuit:
[image]

But my output pulse width is dependent on the trigger circuit.

For example in the above circuit according to the formula $$T=1.1RC$$
I expect to have \$1100\mu\$s width but it has \$2053\mu\$s width on the output.

Comment: I think you forget to attach your circuit :)

Comment: No,Image is Clear..

Comment: Tried it in 3 different browsers with no success

Comment: Please Now try...

Comment: It's working now

Comment: I think that C2 is too big and it cause the trigger pin to take a long time to recover. I would try decreasing the value of C2 to 100nF and see the circuit behavior.

Comment: Non,I Change C2 to 100nF and Now I don't Have any output(Means It's always is zero)

Comment: Why You want to use such a weird circuit at the trigger? Think about this (from 555 datasheet): "During the timing cycle when the output is high, the
further application of a trigger pulse will not effect the circuit so long as the trigger input is returned high at least 10μs before the end of the timing interval."

Comment: yes,it's true.but what is must change in my circuit?

Answer (score 1):

A 555 trigger pulse must be shorter than the output pulse or else the output pulse will just follow the input pulse.

[image]

Comment: after your change According to formula i must have 1100 us pulse width but it had 893 us width..!?

Comment: Hmm... I wasn't paying attention and I made an error: R2 and R3 should go back to 1k, and C1 should stay at 100 nF, which will make your trigger pulse about 51 microseconds wide. If you still have problems with the output pulse width after you make the changes, look at the tolerances of R1 and C1, and take a look at the 555's data sheet for the timer's initial accuracy.